# Gutenberg publish date datepicker

Tags: publish, datepicker

I'm making some meta boxes to my custom posts, and i need a datepicker

[image]

Is there a way to use this wordpress datetimepicker but without the time?

Comment: Have you used it and can not remove the time part?

Comment: @NathanPowell no, I haven't used it. Searched at wp documentation and found only about jQuery ui datepicker which are totally different

Comment: It looks like that is a React component: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src/date-time

Answer (score 0):

for less time you can use ACF plugin for this 
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/